# Changing UINavigation controller to work with SlidePanel

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to change my existing setup to work with a SlidePanel. The slide panel is from JA here:- https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels

My Existing code is as follows:
App Delegate did finish launching:

```
welcomeViewController = [[MySpyWelcomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyWelcomeViewController" bundle:nil];

navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:welcomeViewController];
navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

self.viewController = self.navController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Once the user is logged in I then call a method which pushes the Home view controller:

```
// Push the homeViewController onto the navController
NSLog(@"presentHomeViewController");
self.navController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
[self.navController setTitle:@"Home"];
[self.navController pushViewController:self.homeViewController animated:NO];
```

In the JA Slide Panel example it shows the following:

```
self.viewController = [[JASidePanelController alloc] init];
self.viewController.leftPanel = [[JALeftViewController alloc] init];
self.viewController.centerPanel = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[JACenterViewController alloc] init]];
self.viewController.rightPanel = [[JARightViewController alloc] init];

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

I am not sure how to implement this into my current layout as the slidepanel treats this as a view controller rather than a navigation controller. Does anyone know how I can implement JASlidePanel into my current implementation?

Answer (score 1):

In your appdelegate.h file do the following:

```
    @class JASidePanelController;
```

then

```
   //just generally declare the JAsidepanelcontroller
    @property (nonatomic,retain) JASidePanelController *homeViewController;
   //This is your loginviewcontroller
    @property (nonatomic,retain) LoginMainController *loginmainController;
```

Then in your appdelegate.m file do the following:

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
     {

        if(loggedin)
       {
         if (!self.homeViewController) {

        MySpyWelcomeViewController *mySpyWelcomeViewControllerTemp = [[MySpyWelcomeViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *navigationControllerTemp = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mySpyWelcomeViewControllerTemp];
        self.navigationController = navigationControllerTemp;

     //here use the left and right viewcontroller that you are going to show for the sidemenu
        SidebarOptionsLeftViewController *sidebarOptionsleftViewControllerTemp = [[SidebarOptionsLeftViewController alloc] init];
        SidebarOptionsRightViewController *sidebarOptionsrightViewControllerTemp = [[SidebarOptionsRightViewController alloc] init];
        sidebarOptionsrightViewControllerTemp.delegate = mySpyWelcomeViewControllerTemp;

        JASidePanelController *homeViewTemp = [[JASidePanelController alloc] init];
        homeViewTemp.shouldDelegateAutorotateToVisiblePanel = NO;

        homeViewTemp.leftPanel = sidebarOptionsleftViewControllerTemp;
        homeViewTemp.centerPanel = navigationControllerTemp;
        homeViewTemp.rightPanel = sidebarOptionsrightViewControllerTemp;
      }
        self.window.rootViewController = self.homeViewController;
      }

   else {
    if (!self.loginmainController) {
        LoginMainController *loginmainControllerTemp = [[LoginMainController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginMainController" bundle:nil];
        self.loginmainController = loginmainControllerTemp;
    }
    if (!self.navigationController) {
        UINavigationController *navigationControllerTemp = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.loginmainController];
        self.navigationController = navigationControllerTemp;
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
  }
```

}

This works well for me.Hope this will help you too.